# How to format person or group field values in c#?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am retrieving my sharepoint list data in c# and assigning into a SPGridview.
The below is the code i am using to fill the SPGridview.
I have a column called "Contact" in my SPGridview, which is mapped to the person or group field.

After binding, when i see the "Contact" column in the SPGridview, i see the results like "Kumar, Ramesh;#55;#Kumar, Amit".
But i want the result like "Kumar, Ramesh;Kumar, Amit".

Please help me how to achieve this.

```
public void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            SPList myList = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["MyList"];
            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();

            query.Query = @"<Where>
      <And>
         <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='Year_x0020_Start' />
            <Value Type='Text'>2010</Value>
         </Eq>
         <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='Year_x0020_End' />
            <Value Type='Text'>2012</Value>
         </Eq>
      </And>
   </Where>";

            DataTable tempTbl = myList.GetItems(query).GetDataTable();
            gdvSearchResults.DataSource = tempTbl;
            gdvSearchResults.DataBind();
}
```

Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but under a different circumstance.  I was using the Content Query Web Part and editing a XSL template.  But the same #55, etc was showing up.  I got rid of it using a regular expression via JavaScript.  Possibly you could do the same but on your DataTable column before it is bound to the SPGridView.  The regular expression I used was:

```
.replace(/[;#0-9]+/g, "; ")
```

I blogged about it here: http://davidpopdan.blogspot.com/2012/11/using-people-picker-with-multiple-names.html

Also, if you're wondering what those numbers are, they're the user's ID, unique to the site collection you're working in.  There's a hidden list that keeps track of that info.